# change the % of an image view in the xml layout

Tags: android, image, imageview, imagebutton

I have a realy big image (over 1000px over 1000px) and when im doing an imagebutton and put the image inside i cant see the whole image.
How can i change the % of the image so that i can present it whithout changing the px itselve?

Changing layout_height and layout_width just change the actual size of the imagebutton itself and not the image size.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/black" />
```

or

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/black" />
```

doesn`t help me...

Comment: add android:scaleType="fitXY" to image..

Comment: You arte not supposed to place such big images in an image button.

Answer (score 0):

Set scaleType to fitCenter:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Answer (score 0):

Drawable
create folder in res folder called `drawable` it must be same name

then create xml file called it `scale` and put this code inside it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/black"
    android:scaleGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:scaleHeight="80%" <!-- or what ever value you want % -->
    android:scaleWidth="80%" /> <!-- or what ever value you want % -->
```

layout

```
   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/scale" />
```